# How to convert a char field to uuid field in django models

Tags: django, django-models, orm

I have a django model, where I am storing uuid kind of strings in a character field of max length 255, I want to convert this field to uuid field, how can this be done in django.

Comment: Can you show how these "uuid kind of strings" look like?

Answer (score -1):

You can write this code in your models.py file.

```
import uuid
```

replace `models.CharField` with `models.UUIDField`. Overall code is:

```
id = models.UUIDField(
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False
    )
```

Then run `makemigrations` and `migrate`